# Batching multiple Reverse-Geocoding requests on Google Maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Is there a way to batch multiple reverse-geocoding requests on the Google Maps API?

I only see simple requests possible:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: I do believe so but what do you mean exactly? you can do 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries as stated in the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Google Geocoding Api Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)**

No, it doesn't let you, as you already noticed, to add multiple addresses, because the required parameter is not an array as stated by documentation:

> Required parameters in a reverse geocoding request: 
>   latlng — The latitude and longitude values specifying the location for which you wish to obtain the closest, human-readable address.

You didn't specify the code context that you are using. Can I suggest you to implement another Google Api? It will be a lot easier to do multiple request via code.

**[Google Geocoding Javascript Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)**

With this Api you can do multiple requests like this:

```
 var locations = [
      { lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312 },
      { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
      { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
      { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 }
];

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  geocodeAddress(locations[i]);
}
```

Full example [here](https://gist.github.com/boldfacedesign/7493845) and documentation example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)